# Finding the image of a complex-valued function and the interpretation

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $f(z) := \frac{1}{z^4 - 1}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C} \ \{\pm 1, \pm i
\}$, show that $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{15}$ if $|z| \geq 2$.

I can prove this, but the interpretation of this; is it: the range of $f$ will be complex numbers, lying inside the circle with centre at the origin, radius $\frac{1}{15}$? If so, it seems that the ""majority"" of complex-valued functions would output points inside some circle (since we can always manipulate the triangle inequality) given some condition on $z$. Am I correct?
Basically my thought after doing the quesion is: "A lot of complex-valued functions can be bounded in absolute value by some real number, meaning that the function's image lies in some circle".

Answer (score 0):

The range of $f$ is the set of *all* $\{f(z) : z \in \operatorname{dom}(f)\}$
where $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ is the domain of $f$, here $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{i,-i,1,-1\}$.

You have just shown that for large values of $|z|$, $f(z)$ will be in that circle, but for other $z$ we can get lots of other values. E.g. try $z = 1+r$ for small reals $r$ close to $0$ e.g.

There is a deep theorem (Picard's theorem) that says that the range of a non-constant differentiable function is either $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{p\}$ for some $p \in \mathbb{C}$. Here you don't have $0$ in the range, e.g.

Comment: How "large" would "large values" be in this context? Rather, how "small" would $|z|$ have to be so that it doesn't map inside this circle? Is there a way to find the set of $r$ values?  
  
(I tested using $r = 0.01$ and indeed, $|\frac{1}{1.01^4 - 1}| = 24.628... > 15$.)

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma: your interpratation of Picard's Theorem is not O.K., since this theorem deals with essential singularities of holomorphic functions. The function above has only poles !

Answer (score 0):

If $|z| \ge 2$, then $|z|^4 \ge 16$. Hence $15 \le |z|^4-1 \le |z^4-1|$.